# Process builder instantly executing scheduled action

Tags: process-builder, process

I have created a scheduled action to send email 1 days after a custom date field and in another process I m setting this date field to today. Both run on create/update records.

So if I create account today I should get mail tomorrow. But to my surprise its instantly sending me email.

Comment: I think there is a mistake somewhere in your logic/process builders or so

Comment: @kurunve I have clearly given 1 day after custom date field but it is instantly executing action.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the process builder that you've created?